# Cropping then resizing with paperclip not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip

I am trying to crop a square section out of a larger rectangular image, and then resize it to a smaller standard size, but every time comes out resized and not cropped at all. I tried doing what they said on [How to crop and then resize with Paperclip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800098/how-to-crop-and-then-resize-with-paperclip) but it still seems not to work...  I tried the same options from the command line manually and it worked as expected.

How would I make this do what I want?

```
has_attached_file :image, styles: {
    small: {
      convert_options: "-gravity NorthWest -crop 608x608+300+27 +repage -resize 200x200^"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Try changing your crop to `-crop 608x608+300+27!` and your resize to `-resize 200x200`. So I am basically suggesting you add `!` (or maybe `\!` if it needs escaping in your environment) to the crop, and that you remove the circumflex (`^`) after the resize.

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: No... still the same